# Neo4j query performance with keyword distinct

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a naive question regarding the use of keyword `DISTINCT`. So basically I have a graph (User-[Likes]->Item) with millions nodes. I want to find distinct users that like a certain item. The following two queries have significant performance difference, and I'm confused. I do create index of :Item(id) and :User(id).

Query 1:

```
profile match (a:Item {id:'001'})<-[:LIKES]-(u:User)
return  count(distinct u);
```

Query 2:

```
profile match (a:Item {id:'001'})<-[:LIKES]-(u:User)
return  distinct u;
```

The first query returns result in seconds, but the second query keeps running for over 5 minutes and I lost patient and stop the query. I thought the second query would be faster than the first query since there is no count aggregation operation, so I don't understand the performance difference.

Comment: Isn't the first query returning a single number, while the second query is returning possibly thousands (or *millions?*) of nodes?

Comment: You should run the second query from a driver, or add LIMIT 100 or so at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first query is only returning the count of distinct values which is an easy job for neo4j.

Whereas your second query is returning all the nodes which are distinct, if your database has too many distinct values it would take a long time. If you just want to have a glimpse at a few distinct values you may add a `limit` to your query.

Eg:

```
profile match (a:Item {id:'001'})<-[:LIKES]-(u:User)
return  distinct u 
limit 5;
```

It returns (random) five users who `like` the Item('001').

Comment: Now I understand. However, instead of listing distinct counts, my task is to list all distinct users and save them same where for process. Does it mean that I have to wait til the query finishes? Is there any alternative more efficient ways? Thanks!